# Does updating the app also update the store even when redux-persist is enabled

Tags: react-native, redux

So I am trying to update my application. I am using redux-persist to persist my store. When I updated, i got an error which i believe occurred because my store persisted and didn't update.

Update:
The error: JS exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating '${anObjectInMyStore's}.length
${After the above message, a bunch of error relating to not finding the object and an error in my RCTView}

Once deleting the app and reinstalling, the app worked fine

Comment: Can you please show the error and any specific code it relates to, as your question is quite broad and opinionated.

Comment: added an update

Comment: So this issue could be that some of your objects in your store is being passed a value that isn't an object, you said it works once deleting so possible one of your screens is accidentally parsing data to your store that isn't an object? Can you share your code for the reducers and any other code that is relating to your store, so we can better analyse it please.

Comment: A lot of the code is wrapped into the work i'm doing, so I can't share it. But thanks for the advice, I'll look into it further